# User defined function output in Shiny not in scope

Tags: shiny

I would like to use a user defined function in Shiny to perform a simple calculation with output two  variables. The function I wrote works when it is not part of a shiny app. However when part of a Shiny, the returned object (dfr) is ‘not in scope’. What am I missing?

```r
library(shiny)

# Function ----------------------------------------------------------------
convert <- function(coef_1, coef_2, vec) {
  part_1 <- coef_1/(2*sin((vec/2)*pi/180))
  part_2 <- 2*(180/pi)*(asin(coef_2/(2*part_1)))
  dfr <- data.frame(part_1, part_2)
  return(dfr)
}
# End Function ------------------------------------------------------------


ui <- fluidPage(
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        textInput("num", h3("Enter number to convert:"), value = NULL)
      ),
      mainPanel(
        verbatimTextOutput("text1", placeholder = TRUE),
        verbatimTextOutput("text2", placeholder = TRUE)
      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  nums_str <- as.character(input$num)
  nums_vector <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(nums_str, split = ",")))
  convert(1.5, 1.1, nums_vector)

  output$text1 <- renderText({
    req(input$num)
    dfr$part_1
    })

  output$text2 <- renderText({
    req(input$num)
    dfr$part_2
    })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: `convert(1.5, 1.1, c(5,10))` just prints a dataframe as output. Use `dfr <- convert(1.5, 1.1, c(5,10))` instead to store the dataframe in `dfr`. But I don't understand why you need `input$num` in this case.

Comment: This works, thank you! Regarding your question, I made a mistake in the example, the 3rd parameter in the function (c(5, 10)) is a vector supposed to be read from the text box. That is why I check that it is not empty.

Comment: Then you'll have to put this in a `reactive()` expression

Comment: I have edited the example to show the right intent i.e. using the text box input as the 3rd argument in the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `input`s, you need to do it in reactive environment, such as `reactive()`, `renderDataTable()`, etc.

Here, you need to run your function in a `reactive()` and then call it with `dfr()` in the outputs.

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  dfr <- reactive({
    convert(1.5, 1.1, as.numeric(input$num))
  })

  output$text1 <- renderText({
    req(input$num)
    dfr()$part_1
  })

  output$text2 <- renderText({
    req(input$num)
    dfr()$part_2
  })

}
```

Since this is quite basic stuff with R Shiny, checking some [tutorials](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson6/) might be very useful.